# Using System.Diagnostics.Process asynchronously, how should I ensure that I've received the last output before determining it has exited?

Tags: c#, .net, asynchronous, process

Consider this example C# code (irrelevant pieces left out):

```
using System.Diagnostics.Process;

var process = new Process();
var startInfo = process.StartInfo;
startInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
startInfo.RedirectStandardError = true;
process.EnableRaisingEvents = true;
process.OutputDataReceived += OutputHandler;
process.ErrorDataReceived += ErrorHandler;
process.Exited += ExitHandler;
process.Start();
process.BeginOutputReadLine();
process.BeginErrorReadLine();
```

Now, I want to notify a listener that the process is finished *after there is no more output (stdout/stderr) to read from it*. How do I ensure in my `ExitHandler` method that all remaining stdout/stderr is processed by `OutputHandler` and `ErrorHandler` before determining that the process has truly finished?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is an interlock when you explicitly use Process.WaitForExit(-1).  It won't return until the asynchronous readers for stdout and stderr have indicated end-of-file status.  Call it in your Exited event handler.  You must use a timeout of -1 or this won't work.  Or just WaitForExit().  Which is fine, you know it already exited.

Comment: So this is a known pattern for ensuring that stdout/stderr handling has finished in the `Exited` handler?

Comment: I see that the documentation for `WaitForExit()` says: *This method instructs the Process component to wait an infinite amount of time for the process and event handlers to exit.* This actually sounds like what I need. I don't think there's any guarantee in the `Exited` handler after all that other event handling has finished.

Comment: I'm marking this as the solution as it seems correct from the reference documentation. I think the negative timeout is unnecessary though, as according to the reference it should correspond to the `WaitForExit()` overload.

Comment: I'm not sure I see what you mean? Your answer definitely was helpful, I just think the -1 is unnecessary, judging by the documentation.

Comment: This is the same as waiting for `WaitForExit()` which was my original answer. I changed it because it doesn't address the question. It's just the synchronous version of waiting for the `Exited` event.

Comment: @TheCodeKing. Well, it turns out one should call `WaitForExit()`, or so it seems at least judging by the reference documentation, since it ensures that event handlers have finished processing first. *This method instructs the Process component to wait an infinite amount of time for the process and event handlers to exit.*

Comment: It's just saying use it to block synchronously until the app exits. It's the same affect as the `Exited` event, although you would need to use the `SynchronizingObject` if you really care about a valid async call occurring after (but fired before) the exit event. i.e. as a reader `Exited` or `WaitForExit` have the same affect, no data is lost.

Answer (score 0):

The [`Exited`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.exited.aspx) event is called when the process aborts or terminates. There should therefore never be a situation whereby there is still data to read.

> When the operating system shuts down a process, any process component
>   that is waiting for an exit is notified. The component can then access
>   the associated process information that is still resident in the
>   operating system memory (such as ExitTime property) by using the
>   handle that it has to the process.
>
> Because the associated process has exited, the Handle property of the
>   component no longer points to an existing process resource. Instead,
>   it can be used only to access the operating system's information about
>   the process resource. The system is aware of handles to exited
>   processes that have not been released by Process components, so it
>   keeps the ExitTime and Handle property information in memory until the
>   Process component specifically frees the resources.

Comment: I should call `WaitForExit` in my `ExitHandler` method?

Comment: Hmm... I thought I experienced once that `OutputHandler` was called in a different thread after `ExitHandler` had been called, with non-null data. Maybe it was for another process (I had started two processes), I'm not quite sure anymore...

Comment: This answer is not correct, the operating system provides no guarantee that threads are called in a timely manner.

Comment: I guess your right it's possible that an event that arrives late after the process has exited. But in this case the data it holds is valid because it was sent before exit and should still be processed. My point was more that after exit there can no longer be any stream events fired.

Comment: Well, it doesn't matter to me if there's any more data to be read from the process, but if there's any more data to be handled. This is also clearly stipulated in my question.